# how to get users that total cont is = 0 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, pivot

I have a problem I need to get the user_id that have total "active" anuncios = 0 ,
this is my query, but when executing it it doesn't bring me anything ... when in theory I have two users without active ads

```
select anuncios.user_id,count(user_id) as total from anuncios where estado = "Activo" group by user_id HAVING total = 0
```

I already tried this way and it doesn't work either

```
select anuncios.user_id,count(user_id) as total from anuncios where estado = "Activo" group by user_id HAVING total IS NULL
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What are the values of `estado` for those _two users without active ads_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause filters out inactive users before you get a chance to display them. You could use conditional aggregation to get the total:

```
select user_id, sum(estado = 'Activo') as total 
from anuncios 
group by user_id
```

You can then add a `having` clause to filter on users whose `estado` is never `'Activo'`:

```
select user_id
from anuncios 
group by user_id 
having sum(estado = 'Activo') = 0
```